# Does Opera Mini proxy filter CSS-hidden elements?

Tags: opera, opera-mini

I have to provide a responsive website targeting Opera Mini devices. I have to make the page's size as small as possible. As Opera Mini uses a proxy to compress page's size, I was wondering if Opera Mini does load hidden elements (like pictures) on the client device if the elements are specified as follows:

```
<img style="display:none" source="..."/>
```

Comment: With Opera Mini you shouldn't have to worry about compressing the page yourself. That's what Opera Mini does very well on its remote proxy servers, which is where the content is being rendered. All the user's client device get, is a highly compressed OBML (Opera Binary Markup Language) version of your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera Turbo does compress images to decrease overall page size. But it does not remove any markup from the code. Furthermore, the compression mechanism can be disabled in the settings (at least in Opera Mobile).